# C# application problem in Release build only

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, build, release

the problem only appears when making Release build and running exe file ( not from visual studio )
in all other combination either it's running from visual studio or running exe everything works fine

I'm running Function Load using backgroundWorker

Load:

```
while (!Request.GAMELIST.XMLReceived) ;

GameEngine.ParseGameList( Request.GAMELIST.XML );

Request.GAMELIST.XMLReceived = false;
```

while loop in this fragment works like delay
it should wait till XML is received from server and then continue
but it stucks in above specified situation

if I'll put MessageBox.show("here we go"); after while loop
messageBox will not appear
but if I'll put MessageBox.show("here we go"); before while loop
application will receive data until I click messagebox ok
and then everything will work fine

here is GAMELIST class implementation

```
public class RequestGAMELIST
{
    public string XML;

    public bool XMLReceived = false;

    public void ParseRequest( string request )
    {
        int index = request.IndexOf(':') + 2;
        XML = request.Substring(index, request.Length - index);
        XMLReceived = true;
    }
}
```

please provide help if you can
this is really strange thing which I can't figure out by my self

Thanks.

Comment: Try making XMLReceived volatile, but you should definitely look into using an event-based system instead of a loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this code has very good odds to hang in the Release build.  The JIT optimizer doesn't know that the variable might be set to true by code outside of the method.  You need to tell it that, like this:

```
public class RequestGAMELIST
{
    public volatile bool XMLReceived = false;
    // etc..
}
```

The volatile keyword ensures that the jitter won't store the variable value in a CPU register.

That solves your problem, it is still not the right way to do it.  You should use an AutoResetEvent instead.  It ensures that the thread responds to the variable change is quickly as possible.  And most importantly, it lets the thread block so it doesn't burn any cpu cycles.

```
public class RequestGAMELIST
{
    public AutoResetEvent XMLReceived = new AutoResetEvent();

    public void ParseRequest( string request )
    {
        int index = request.IndexOf(':') + 2;
        XML = request.Substring(index, request.Length - index);
        XMLReceived.Set();
    }

}
```

In your thread:

```
    XMLReceived.WaitOne();
    GameEngine.ParseGameList( Request.GAMELIST.XML );
```

Comment: thanks that looks like very cool solution.
I never heared about AutoResetEvent before.

does .WaitOne(); automatically unsets ?

thank you I'll try solution and write result

Comment: Yes, that's what Auto means.  As opposed to ManualResetEvent, it requires calling Reset() yourself.

Comment: @Hans Passant I tried but still no luck. know if I write messagebox pop up anywhere in that function it will not appear

Comment: You don't give me anything to help you.  Learning how to write thread-safe code does take several months of your life, I think you just got started.

Comment: does the WaitOne() block the current thread ? even volatile bool solution doesn't work

Comment: If the bool doesn't work then the code must not be running.  Use the debugger.  Debug + Windows + Threads is crucial to find out what the threads are doing.  Double-click one to switch context, look at its Call Stack.

Comment: @Hans Passant I fixed everything. your solution worked perfectly. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

This is a **bad** idea:

```
while (!Request.GAMELIST.XMLReceived) ;
```

At least you should be doing something like:

```
while (!Request.GAMELIST.XMLReceived) {
  System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);  // Don't hog the CPU!
}
```

Your program runs fine in debug mode perhaps due to certain debug routines added inside the while loop which makes it run slower...

Comment: Depending on the classes/API used, if the code is waiting for something from the server then there should be a synchronization primitive available from the call.

Comment: Especially when running in a thread which has limited resources, you **definitely shouldn't** hog the CPU by running a tight loop without yielding.  You CPU (or the core on your CPU that this is running) is going to be at 100% utilization all the time.

Comment: yeah I was wrong 

problem is wrong CPU usage

you said At least you should be doing something like
do you know even better solution ?

Comment: I tried
while( !Request.GAMELIST.XMLReceived )
{
  Thread.Sleep(100);
}
but it still stucks

Comment: In that case, it is obvious that the variable Request.GAMELIST.XMLReceived got optimized away by the optimizer when  you build for Release.  It must be a variable that the compiler thinks never changes (i.e. is always false), so it just optimizes it into an infinite loop.  Is this variable set somewhere else by some other library code?  Maybe you should mark this variable as volatile.